# What is required to transform root web.config from subfolder config transforms?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web.config-transform

[image: Project structure]

So, I have this structure with one web.config in my root and one web.config in a subfolder named Config. I want to transform the root web.config upon build. I know this can be achieved but I do not know how.

I have seen this in another project with no post or pre build actions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this tool called SlowCheetah:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5

promoted by Scott Hanselman:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SlowCheetahWebconfigTransformationSyntaxNowGeneralizedForAnyXMLConfigurationFile.aspx

This is a visual studio extension that allows you to transform xml files in sub folders - I assume this is what you want. As far as I can remember it works for TFS build server as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is doable with built in features and a little modification to your csproj file.

Add these lines to your csproj file and it will create an updated web.config on every build. It takes your web.config file in the Config folder, applies a transform on it from the selected transform config file, and then puts the output in the root directory.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <BuildDependsOn>
        CustomWebConfigTransform;
        $(BuildDependsOn);
    </BuildDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="CustomWebConfigTransform">
    <TransformXml source="$(ProjectDir)\Config\Web.config"  
    transform="$(ProjectDir)\Config\Web.$(Configuration).config"  
    destination="Web.config" />  
</Target>
```

I have confirmed this works for subfolders. I use a version of this without subfolders for my web API projects. I recommend excluding the root web.config file from source control as it will change every time you build with a different configuration.

Also, if your build server doesn't have the web developer tools available, the transform will not work.